# QML module not recognized by Bazel build

Tags: c++, qt, qml, bazel, bzlmod

Currently, I try to build the Spotify demo described in the  [Qt QML Book](https://www.qt.io/product/qt6/qml-book/ch13-networking-authentication) using [rules_qt6](https://github.com/Vertexwahn/rules_qt6) with Bazel. I did setup a PR [here](https://github.com/Vertexwahn/rules_qt6/pull/20).

The CMake variant of it has the following CMake function

```py
qt_add_qml_module(SpotifyOAuth
    VERSION 1.0.0
    URI Spotify
    QML_FILES
        main.qml
    SOURCES
        spotifyapi.h spotifyapi.cpp
        spotifymodel.h spotifymodel.cpp
)
```

[`rules_qt6`](https://github.com/Vertexwahn/rules_qt6) does not offer a `qt_add_qml_module` rule currently.  Neverthless, maybe with some workaround, this demo could get working. I know too less about the details of `qt_add_qml_module` to implement it currently.

I built the CMake version of the Spotify demo and have seen that it generates a `qmldir` file:

```
module Spotify
typeinfo SpotifyOAuth.qmltypes
prefer :/Spotify/
```

I tried to add those files (`qmldir` and `SpotifyOAuth.qmltypes`) via a Qt resource but on runtime I get still this error:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/Spotify/main.qml:52:5: SpotifyAPI is not a type
```

You can run the demo via:

```bash
bazel run --config=gcc11 //Spotify:SpotifyOAuth # Ubuntu 22.04
bazel run --config=macos //Spotify:SpotifyOAuth # macOS
bazel run --config=vs2022 //Spotify:SpotifyOAuth # Windows + Visual Studio 2022
```

I am searching for ways to get this demo working by using the pre-generated files (i.e. `qmldir`, `SpotifyOAuth.qmltypes`) or by implementing a `qt_add_qml_module` Bazel macro/rule.

My build file looks currently like this:

```
load("@rules_qt//:qt.bzl", "qt_cc_binary", "qt_cc_library", "qt_resource")

qt_resource(
    name = "qrc",
    files = [
        "SpotifyOAuth.qmltypes",
        "qmldir",
    ],
)

qt_resource(
    name = "qrc2",
    files = [
        "main.qml"
    ],
)

qt_cc_library(
    name = "spotify",
    srcs = [
        "spotifyapi.cpp",
        "spotifymodel.cpp",
    ],
    hdrs = [
        "spotifyapi.h",
        "spotifymodel.h",
    ],
    deps = [
        "@rules_qt//:qt",
    ],
)

qt_cc_binary(
    name = "SpotifyOAuth",
    srcs = [
        "main.cpp",
    ],
    deps = [
        ":qrc",
        ":qrc2",
        ":spotify",
        "@rules_qt//:qt",
    ],
    data = [
        ":qrc",
        ":qrc2",
    ]
)
```

Maybe I have to provide a `SpotifyModel.qml` and `SpotifyAPI.qml` file myself, which define the API of the corresponding C++ components. Not sure about this. Any solutions are welcome!

Comment: Based on your PR, your **qmldir** file is incorrect and doesn't contain any types. Also, you should add your resources root directory to your engine, unless it won't work.